# Merge/Combine filtered ID with same key value in array - Unique in Multidimensional - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, unique

I have multidimensional result of an array which contain number of array object, need to apply filter in array by unique id for duplication and merge/combine else filtered id with same key value pair of array. Like below desired result

This want to be need for the services.

**Result Set**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24901
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25669
            [course_title_code] => VTM 002
            [instructors_name] => Ali_Al
            [course_code] => 8732
            [unique_id] => VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26011
            [course_title_code] => VTM 002
            [instructors_name] => Ali_Al
            [course_code] => 8732
            [unique_id] => VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29502
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 49202
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )    

)
```

**Desired Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24901,29502,49202
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25669,26011
            [course_title_code] => VTM 002
            [instructors_name] => Ali_Al
            [course_code] => 8732
            [unique_id] => VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al
        )
)
```

My current implementation attempts to do something like this:

```
$data = array_unique_by_key($data, 'unique_id');

function array_unique_by_key (&$array, $key) {
    $tmp = array();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $p => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value[$key], $tmp)) {
            array_push($tmp, $value[$key]);
            array_push($result, $value);
        }else{
            $result[$p] = $value['id'];
        }
    }
    return $array = $result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to come from a database, doesn't it?

Comment: what is your output with the above code?

Comment: Yup data come from database but i can't apply this logic that end @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: Why not? Don't you have access to the SQL?

Comment: It returned me filtered ids but not merged @SyedMohamedAladeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was nearly there, just needed to append values in new array on basis on unique value,

if key already exists append id otherwise, append whole array

and there after update the keys as numeric using `array_values` if needed

```
$x = array(
    0 => array
        (
            'id' => '24901',
            'course_title_code' => 'VTM 001',
            'instructors_name' => 'Master_Al_Za',
            'course_code' => '8734',
            'unique_id' => 'VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za',
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'id' => '25669',
            'course_title_code' => 'VTM 002',
            'instructors_name' => 'Ali_Al',
            'course_code' => '8732',
            'unique_id' => 'VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al',
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'id' => '26011',
            'course_title_code' => 'VTM 002',
            'instructors_name' => 'Ali_Al',
            'course_code' => '8732',
            'unique_id' => 'VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al',
        ),

    3 => array
        (
            'id' => '29502',
            'course_title_code' => 'VTM 001',
            'instructors_name' => 'Master_Al_Za',
            'course_code' => '8734',
            'unique_id' => 'VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za',
        ),

    4 => array
        (
            'id' => '49202',
            'course_title_code' => 'VTM 001',
            'instructors_name' => 'Master_Al_Za',
            'course_code' => '8734',
            'unique_id' => 'VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za',
        )    

);
$data = array_unique_by_key($x, 'unique_id');

function array_unique_by_key (&$array, $key) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $p => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($value[$key], $result)) {
            $result[$value[$key]] = $value;
        }else{
            $result[$value[$key]]['id'] .= ',' . $value['id'];
        }
    }
    return array_values($result);
}

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24901,29502,49202
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25669,26011
            [course_title_code] => VTM 002
            [instructors_name] => Ali_Al
            [course_code] => 8732
            [unique_id] => VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Produces exact output required. Concatenates duplicate values with a comma:

```
function mergeArrayOnKey($array, $key){
    $keychain = $ret = array();
    foreach($array as $a){
        if(!isset($a[$key])) continue;
        if(!in_array($a[$key], $keychain)){
            array_push($keychain, $a[$key]);
            array_push($ret, $a);
        }else{
            // Get sub array
            foreach($ret as $k=>$r){
                if($r[$key] == $a[$key]){
                    foreach($a as $kk=>$vv){
                        $oldvals = explode(",",$r[$kk]);
                        if(in_array($vv, $oldvals)) continue;
                        array_push($oldvals,$vv);
                        $r[$kk] = implode(",",$oldvals);
                    }
                }
                $ret[$k] = $r;
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://3v4l.org/4DNgt

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24901,29502,49202
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25669,26011
            [course_title_code] => VTM 002
            [instructors_name] => Ali_Al
            [course_code] => 8732
            [unique_id] => VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be the solution. I only test for 3 value, Please check and let me know. There are some offset warning, ignore them.

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/SX9In), You can check it online.

**Array:**

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        "id" => 24901,
        "course_title_code" => "VTM 001",
        "instructors_name" => "Master_Al_Za",
        "course_code" => 8734,
        "unique_id" => "VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 25669,
        "course_title_code" => "VTM 002",
        "instructors_name" => "Ali_Al",
        "course_code" => 8732,
        "unique_id" => "VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 26011,
        "course_title_code" => "VTM 002",
        "instructors_name" => "Ali_Al",
        "course_code" => 8732,
        "unique_id" => "VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al"
    )
);
```

**Mechanism:**

```
$out = array();
$uni_key = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $srch = array_search($val['unique_id'], $uni_key);
    if($srch > -1){
        $out[$srch]['id'] .= $out[$key]['id'].", ".$val['id'];
    }else{
        array_push($uni_key, $val['unique_id']);
        $out[$key] = $val;      
    }       
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24901
            [course_title_code] => VTM 001
            [instructors_name] => Master_Al_Za
            [course_code] => 8734
            [unique_id] => VTM_001_8734_Master_Al_Za
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25669, 26011
            [course_title_code] => VTM 002
            [instructors_name] => Ali_Al
            [course_code] => 8732
            [unique_id] => VTM_002_8732_Ali_Al
        )

)
```

Comment: Not working properly it getting me warning in line `$out[$srch]['id'] .= $out[$key]['id'].", ".$val['id'];` some of states its working

Comment: @QueryMaster well i already said that there is some warning, you can set some `isset` or `@` before the variables. And i must say this will work. I check it online.

Comment: I have check same in online but it not filtered properly could you please check this from my online id https://3v4l.org/OQLaG

Comment: @QueryMaster, got it. use `if($srch > -1)` instead of `if($srch)`.